# Overwrite Redis method

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-redis

I try to add an option to my app to toggle using a cache. For cache I am using Redis and made simple wrapper for that. The problem is coming when I try to overwrite redis.get method, it's simply doens't work or cannot found `this`.

```
'use strict';

const redis = require('redis');
const config = require('../config');

const REDIS_EMPTY_VALUE = 'NOT_EXIST';
const MINUTE = 60;

let client = redis.createClient({
    host: config.get('REDIS_HOST'),
    port: config.get('REDIS_PORT')
});

client.on("error", function (err) {
    logging.error('Redis Error: ' + err);
    throw new Error(err);
});

/**
 * Next are custom extensions for Redis module
 */
client.emptyValue = REDIS_EMPTY_VALUE;
client.minute = MINUTE;
client.setAndExprire = function(key, value, expire) {
    this.set(key, value);
    this.expire(key, expire);
};

// Here is the problem
client.get = function(key, cb) {
    if (config.get('disable-cache') === 'true') return cb(null, null);
    return client.get(key, cb);
}

module.exports = client;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you override client.get, the client.get become the new function that you defined. So that, you can call to the function that come along with redis package. You can use another object (custom) to call the redis function like below:

```
'use strict';

const redis = require('redis');
const config = require('../config');

const REDIS_EMPTY_VALUE = 'NOT_EXIST';
const MINUTE = 60;

const definedFunctions = [
    'hgetall', 'hexists', 'hmset', 'hmget', 'hkeys', 'hvals', 'hget', 'hset', 'hdel',
    'mget', 'mset', 'set', 'del', 'exists', 'lpush', 'lrange',
    'zrange', 'zrem', 'zadd', 'zrangebyscore', 'zrevrangebyscore',
    'expire', 'incrby'
];

let client = redis.createClient({
    host: config.get('REDIS_HOST'),
    port: config.get('REDIS_PORT')
});

client.on("error", function (err) {
    console.error('Redis Error: ' + err);
    throw new Error(err);
});

/**
 * Next are custom extensions for Redis module
 */

const custom = {
  emptyValue: REDIS_EMPTY_VALUE,
  minute: MINUTE
};

definedFunctions.map((fn) => {
  custom[fn] = (...args) => {
    return client[fn](args);
  };
});

custom.get = function(key, cb) {
    if (config.get('disable-cache') === 'true') return cb(null, null);
    return client.get(key, cb);
}

module.exports = custom;
```